# ¿Por qué mi compilador no acepta fork (), a pesar de mi inclusión de <unistd.h>?

Tags: c

He intentado desinstalar clion y MinGW-w64 - for 32 and 64 bit Windows por si había algún problema pero sigue sin funcionar.

Aparte de la función `fork()` también me pasa con los signals.

El error que me aparece es

> Implicit declaration of function 'fork' is invalid in C99

pero yo siempre que creo un nuevo proyecto lo inicio con C11.

```
fill = fork();
```

Comment: No hay `fork()` en Windows

Comment: ¿No hay ninguna opción para que pueda utilizarlo? @abulafia

Comment: No en windows. Si estás aprendiendo cómo va esa función o haciendo prácticas de alguna asignatura, la única opción es que eso lo hagas en un Linux (puedes crear una máquina virtual para ello, o investigar cómo va eso de WSL --Windows Subsystem for Linux-- que te permite instalar por ejemplo Ubuntu dentro de Windows pero que nunca he usado, o usar cygwin, una "emulación" de linux para Windows, bastante obsoleta ya, me temo). Ya que también mencionas el uso de signal, supongo que esta es la vía que te queda, pues eso es también un concepto Linux.

Comment: Algunos compiladores en línea si reconocen `fork();`, sería cuestión de ver cuál te conviene

Comment: ya solucione el problema instalando Windows Subsystem for Linux que es lo mas facil gracias